# Expand of $(x+y+z+...)^{n}$

Tags: calculus

What is the following polynomial extension?

$\left( x+y+z+ \dots \right)^{n}$

Comment: What does ... mean? Till infinity or what?

Comment: Try this ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the Binomial Theorem of Newton several times to get $$(a+b+c+d+\ldots)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}a^{n-k}(b+c+d+\ldots)^k.$$ And we get
$$(b+c+d+\ldots)^k=\sum_{j=0}^k{k\choose j}b^{k-j}(c+d+\ldots)^j$$ and so on. It becomes a very long summation of summations.